# Label points in QGIS with centre position preferred, but other positions acceptable

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am labeling points in QGIS without displaying a symbol.

The preferred position for the label is centred over the point, but otherwise, any placement around the point is acceptable.

Is this possible? Otherwise, some points are not getting labelled when there is plenty of space available (the green points are a copy of the layer):

[image]

If I select "Cartographic", the placement can be anywhere around the feature, but not centred.

If I select "Around Point", this is similar to "Cartographic" other than the preferred location.

If I select "Offset from Point" (which is the one selected in the diagram above), and choose the centre quadrant, then I can get the label centred. But I can't then see a way of getting a fallback position if the centre position has a collision.

[image]

I have fiddled with using the Geometry Generator to generate a polygon or a line from the point, but the results were also flawed.

Comment: I was gonna suggest using Position priority under the Cartographic placement mode, but unfortunately that doesn't allow labels directly on top. I think the only alternative is to manually move the offending labels, or assign a value to the featueres you think will have issues and refer to that in the Data-defined override of the Quadrant setting.

Comment: Yeah, was hoping that there might be some kind of hack for an automated way! Sounds like I may need to write a feature request. Doesn't seem like it would be overly hard to implement given it could be Cartographic with one extra candidate position (on top, with highest priority)